# Removing certain characters from a string in R

Tags: string, r

I have a string in R which contains a large amount of words. When viewing the string I get a large amount of text which includes text similar to the following:

```
>docs

....

\u009cYes yes for ever for ever the boys cried in their ringing voices with softened faces

....
```

So I'm wondering how to remove these \u009 characters (all of them, some of which have slightly different numbers) from the string. I've tried using `gsub()`, but that wasn't effective in removing the content from the strings.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This should work

```
gsub('\u009c','','\u009cYes yes for ever for ever the boys ')
"Yes yes for ever for ever the boys "
```

Here 009c is the hexadecimal number of unicode.  You must always specify 4 hexadecimal digits.
If you have many , one solution is to separate them by a pipe:

```
gsub('\u009c|\u00F0','','\u009cYes yes \u00F0for ever for ever the boys and the girls')

"Yes yes for ever for ever the boys and the girls"
```

Comment: regarding "you must always specify 4 digits":

This is only when doing unicode. This should remove spaces and dashes just fine:
`gsub(' |-', '', '   1-444-654  ')`

Comment: I was wondering, isn't there a function similar to Excel's right() or left()?

Answer (score 12):

try:
`gsub('\\$', '', '$5.00$')`

Comment: As simple as possible but not simpler. Perfect!