# Need to remove "--" from observations in just one variable in R

Tags: r

I have one variable where all the observations have an "--" before the entry. See below:

Color:
--Orange
--Orange
--Blue
--Pink
--Pink-Purple
--Orange-Red

I want to remove only and all "--" from just the "Color" variable. Does anyone have a solution? Very new to R. Thanks!

Comment: Read up on [`?sub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/grep.html), I think it'll likely do what you want. (Perhaps as simple as `sub("^--", "", x$Color)`, but without actual data it's just a guess.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing certain characters from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170250/removing-certain-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove character from string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973681/remove-character-from-string-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

If the first two characters **always** need to be removed you can simply use substring:

```
substring(c("--Red", "--Yellow"), 3)
```